# FastAPI endpoint can upload .txt but fails on uploading .pdf. How to resolve this?

Tags: upload, fastapi

I'll provide a copy of my endpoint

```
@app.post("/uploadfile/")
def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    upload_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "uploads")
    # Create the upload directory if it doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(upload_dir):
        os.makedirs(upload_dir)

    # get the destination path
    dest = os.path.join(upload_dir, file.filename)
    print(dest)

    file.file.seek(0)
    # copy the file contents
    with open(dest, 'wb') as out_file:
        content = file.file.read()
        out_file.write(content)  
    
    return {"filename": file.filename}
```

The issue that I end up having is when I upload a .pdf file it is 0 bytes in the upload directory.

I tested with .txt and noticed that it did in fact work in that case. I've tried solutions on this site (such as async and without) but everything I found still comes back to this issue.